# Making a 'graph-like' circuit schematic

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, ground

I would like to make a parallel circuit with two resistors to most-closely resemble how a 'graph' would look, for example:

[image]

However, when I try doing something like this in Everycircuit it fails (though it works if the `-` side of the battery terminal is also connected to ground). For example:

[image]

A couple questions here:

- Is my drawing a valid circuit? Or is it not valid until the 'negative side of the battery is grounded' ?
- If it's valid, why doesn't Everycircuit accept that? Are there any other circuit programs that would accept it? I have an easier time understanding circuits when drawn closer to the top drawing than in the 'box-like' schematics.

Comment: The negative end of your 9V source goes nowhere. Current needs to travel in a loop (i.e. it needs to be connected to ground). It is not clear what you are trying to do either. I have no idea what you mean by "graph".

Comment: @DKNguyen is the drawing that I've done valid? Or that is also incomplete.

Comment: Bottom picture is a legible schematic that won't work, and your top picture isn't a schematic at all. Compare the two distinct, labelled terminals in the 9V in your bottom with the 9V in the top which has two unlabelled terminals which may or may not actually be the same terminal.

Comment: Your 0 in the top circuit has a similar issue in that it has two terminals which may or may not be the same terminal, but in the bottom it is very clear it is just a single connection to ground that is split up, not multiple distinct connections. In other words, you are playing fast and loose with what two terminals going to a circle actually represents in your top image: They are always unlabelled and sometimes they represent multiple connections to the same place (i.e. just one pin), while other times they represent multiple distinct connections (multiple pins).

Comment: This is a Thevenin graphical example http://tinyurl.com/hkazlmb

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 -- are you saying that the first graph I've drawn is the above? If so that's great, and that's what I'll look into!

Comment: yes.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit is open so no current can flow. You must connect the battery negative to the other end of the circuit.

The convention is that we use the ground symbol to signify points that are connected on the common reference. This can be handy in a complex schematic as it avoids many wires, connections and cross-overs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPRLtw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Your circuit drawn conventionally in three slightly different formats. Electrically they are all the same.*

You have used the earth symbol which, in my part of the world (Europe) signifies that it is actually connected to an earth rod or, as the symbol suggests, metal plates buried in the ground. (Come to think of it, yours doesn't suggest that as you have it rotated 90°. They should always point down to the earth.)

In drawing schematics the convention is that the higher voltage is generally at the top of the page and negative at the bottom. That way current flows from top to bottom and voltage reduces from top to bottom. You can invent your own scheme but, similar to inventing your own language, you'll find it difficult to communicate with others.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMdXyD.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Another way - prompted by @DKNguyan.*

Comment: I would be wary and specify you are drawing corrected versions of what he has shown in his bottom schematic. It is impossible to tell what his top schematic is trying to be or if the bottom schematic even represents what he thinks his top schematic represents (whether it's supposed to be two parallel resistors or two series resistors). You could also perhaps include top-bottom drawings of the circuit since OP seems very unfamiliar with how circuits can be drawn or interpreted.

Comment: I just threw the schematic in for you, if you're okay with that.

Comment: That's a schematic for the deaf! It doesn't look like one of mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear what you're trying to do with your hand-drawn schematic.

Drawing the direction that you think current should go may help with that - Both in your  understanding of the circuit, and our understanding in what you want out of the ECAD tool.

With regard to your CAD schematic:

Your voltage source in that configuration doesn't do anything. If it were to be taken out, nothing in circuit would act any differently - The left / negative side of your voltage source is floating, and therefore has no effect on the circuit.

If you relate that back to your hand-drawn schematic, note that you have two wires going into the voltage source bubble. Draw a + on the top wire, and a - on the bottom wire, and you should see the solution to what I think you are trying to do.